# Installation of igraph package of R in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, igraph

I am using the following command for the installation of igraph package of R in ubuntu : `install.packages("igraph")`

But I am getting an error saying:

> Warning: unable to access index for repository
>   http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
>   'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES' Warning messages:
>   package ‘igraph’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

Can someone please guide regarding this problem, where I am going wrong in this...

Answer (score 7):

You *probably* want a binary package anyway, and I recently re-explained how to do this:

The easiest way is something like this (and I am showing only the commands, not the output while I do this in a Docker instance of Ubuntu 16.04, and I am doing this in Docker where the account is `root`; otherwise add `sudo` in front)

```
apt-get update     # refresh
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u"
apt-get update     # now with new repos
apt-get install r-cran-igraph
```

and it will *just work* with all its dependencies.  You didn't tell us what Ubuntu version you have.  What I showed works eg in Ubuntu 16.04; for much older releases you need a different package for the `add-apt-repository` command.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect either the server is down or your network is down or you need to go via a proxy.

I can duplicate this message by setting an unobtainable CRAN mirror with:

```
> options(repos="http://example.com/")
> install.packages("foo")
Installing package into ‘/nobackup/rowlings/RLibrary/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://example.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://example.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Warning message:
package ‘foo’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

So either try again and maybe the server is up, or check your local network is okay, or try another CRAN mirror, or check with your local network admins to see if you need to set a proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

you have to install build-essential first

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

also on Ubuntu and Debian Linux the lixml2 and libxml2-dev packages are needed to install to R.

if that does not work check the [webpage](http://igraph.org/r/) of the package for extra documentation

Comment: Unlikely to be the problem, the install process hasn't got that far.

Comment: Also, make it `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` which is a super-set for R particularly.