# Warning messages: 1: In install.packages("poppr") : installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, package

After installing R(3.4.2), and RStudio(1.1.383),  then R package 'poppr' I get these 5 warning messages:

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In install.packages("poppr") :
>   installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status
> 2: In install.packages("poppr") :
>   installation of package ‘phangorn’ had non-zero exit status
> 3: In install.packages("poppr") :
>   installation of package ‘adegenet’ had non-zero exit status
> 4: In install.packages("poppr") :
>   installation of package ‘pegas’ had non-zero exit status
> 5: In install.packages("poppr") :
>   installation of package ‘poppr’ had non-zero exit status
> >
> ```

How will i install package 'poppr'?  TIA

Comment: Run `install.packages("igraph")` and paste the full output here

Comment: What linux distro are you running? If you're running Ubuntu, try the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41045860/8386140) where [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) explains how to get `igraph` up and running on an Ubuntu system. I suspect successfully installing `igraph` will fix all your problems.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: problem resolved by pointing to proper /lib folder